# Mutiple filter options for one variable

Tags: php, filter, sanitization

I'm doing a get request with variable:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
```

Now I would like to add some filtering option:

```
$url = (filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
```

How do I include another filter option: `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`

Putting them next to each other doesn't work. I tried with array that also didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about:

```
$url = filter_var(filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Comment: Thanks it seems to work, Im happy:) Do you think I can add as much filters or is it limited to take two filters?

Comment: its standard php, if the functions are returning strings you can wrap up as many as you like, but its harder to debug and  read the code.

Answer (score 1):

Why even sacrifice clarity for non-beneficial approach? Just keep it clear, simple.

```
$url = filter_var($_GET['url'], FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$final = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by "non-beneficial approach" Does this process faster than Dagon's answer ?

Comment: @Youss nither is faster afaik. But, codding simple helps you debug/read your code easily in the future. For you, or another programmer as well.

Comment: Im working with cURL (and simple html dom) and it doesn't work well when adding: `$ch = curl_init($final);` The page gets screwed up. Thanks anyway, I definitely learned something and will keep this approach in mind.